# Let $\rho$ be a normal operator, show $\rho^*(v) = 0 \iff \rho(v) = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators

> Let $\rho$ be a normal operator, show that $\rho^*(v) = 0 \iff \rho(v) = 0$

My attempt:

$\Rightarrow$

$\langle \rho(v),v\rangle = \langle v,\rho^*(v)\rangle = \langle v,0\rangle = 0 \Rightarrow \rho(v) = 0.$

$\Leftarrow$

$\langle \rho(v),v\rangle = \langle 0,v\rangle = \langle v,\rho^*(v)\rangle = 0 \Rightarrow \rho^*(v) = 0.$

Is it right or that also implies $v=0$?

Comment: Just asking... $\rho(v)=0$ $\iff$ $\langle \rho (v),v\rangle=0$ or maybe  $\rho(v)=0$ $\iff$ $\langle \rho (v),u\rangle=0$ for any $u\ne0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\langle \rho(v),v\rangle=0$ only means that $\rho (v)$ is perpendicular to $v $. Proceed as given below:

$$
\begin {align*}
\langle \rho(v),\rho (v)\rangle &= \langle v,\rho^*\rho(v)\rangle\\
& = \langle v,\rho\rho^*(v)\rangle = 0.
\end {align*}$$

Comment: How did you get $\langle \rho(v),\rho (v)\rangle = \langle \rho (v),\rho^*\rho(v)\rangle$? Shouldn't be $\langle \rho(v),\rho (v)\rangle = \langle v,\rho^*\rho(v)\rangle$?

Comment: @Mystery Yes, it was a typo.